# Why static_assert is a declaration instead of a postfix-expression in C++ syntax?

Tags: c++, syntax

I just perceived that `static_assert` is defined as a `static_assert-declaration`.

By my understanding, the declaration should introduce a name, function name/object name or type name. `static_assert` doesn't fit into this. This is not intuitive.

So why is `static_assert` defined as a declaration instead of a `postfix-expression` statement?

Follows the relevant part of the standard:

```
static_assert-declaration:
     static_assert ( constant-expression , string-literal ) ;
```

Comment: This way, it can appear at namespace scope. Statements can't.

Comment: @Igor: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, the big difference between static assertions and classic regular `assert` is that `assert` is an *executable* assertion. It is a run-time assertion that has to be executed in order to do its job. For this reason, it has to be a statement or an expression. (It happens to be an expression.) Meanwhile, static assertion works completely differently: is not an executable assertion, it is a *compile-time* assertion. So, it is not naturally restricted to being a statement or an expression.

Secondly, it has to be able to appear where expressions are not allowed to appear by themselves - in namespace scope and among class member declarations. In order to support such placement it has to be either a declaration or something completely new. The language authors decided not to introduce a new kind of entity and simply made it a declaration.

Thirdly, in C++11 a declaration does not necessarily introduce a name. For example, C++11 supports empty declaration and attribute declaration, neither of which introduces names. Specifically for that reason in C++11 the description of the basic concept of *declaration* was changed from

> A declaration introduces names into a translation unit or redeclares
>   names introduced by previous declarations. (C++03)

to

> A declaration **may** introduce one or more names into a translation unit
>   or redeclare names introduced by previous declarations. (C++11)

Comment: Wow! I even think there may be no reasoning. But there is a lot of thing I didn't know about it. I will mark this as answer.